# VM snapshot to be taken using rundeck

Tags: vmware, rundeck

IS there a plugin in rundeck to trigger vm snapshot and datastore backup in rundeck .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at this moment, but you can create a bash script-step Rundeck job to make a snapshot and restore it using the VMware CLI tool (vmware-cmd). Take a [look](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2012964).